# unable to zip the folder which is having multi type of contents using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, zip

```
zip --symlinks -q -r /cygdrive/d/folderA/folderA.zip folderA/
```

this is how I am using the zip command in bash script,
but after running that bash script, the resulted zip is having only one folder. it is not taking whole data while doing zip operation using bash script.

But on normal command prompt, it is working as expected.

Comment: @oguz ismail, i am able to understand whta changes you made in that command?
could you please explain if possible?

Comment: I didn't change anything, I just put that into a code block. See the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60721919/revisions)